# Node: Command line utitly in Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

I am writing a basic command line utility using node in Windows. Here is the file `kevin.js`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log("Hello");
```

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "kevin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "preferGlobal": "true",
  "bin":{
    "kevin":"kevin.js"
  }
}
```

When I execute `node kevin.js` it works. `npm link` command also works fine. But when i try to execute my command `kevin`, it does not execute, instead opens the file in Notepad.

Comment: Windows does not understand the #!/usr/bin/env node part of your script.  You have to run it as 'node kevin.js'

Answer (score 3):

you can create kevin.cmd (or kevin.bat) with the command to run your tool (e.g.: node kevin.js) and put it somewhere in the system PATH. That's what most of the tools do (like uglifyjs, less, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You can associate a file extension with a default "runtime" environment.

See my explanation on how to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6818266/330315

Once you have done it, you can simply type "kevin" in the commandline and it will be executed using node.js