# How to insert python code in a bat file?

Tags: batch-file, ipython

Would like to insert python code 
or run ipython code in a windows bat file
(Not in a separate .py file).

After searching, could not find any solution.

EDIT:
This is for ipython code (not python).

Answer (score 11):

Try this (batch-python polyglot script ):

```
0<0# : ^
''' 
@echo off
echo batch code
python "%~f0" %*
exit /b 0
'''

print("python code")
```

the `'''` respectively starts and ends python multi line comments.

`0<0# : ^` is more interesting  - due to redirection priority in batch it will be interpreted like `:0<0# ^` by the batch script which is a label which execution will be not displayed on the screen. The caret at the end will escape the new line and second line will be attached to the first line.For python it will be `0<0` statement and a start of inline comment.

The credit goes to [siberia-man](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5543&start=30)

Comment: What about if I want to run ipython execution interpreter ?

Comment: @quantCode - honestly I don't know.I've never heard of ipython before. May its syntax is the same? Have you tried it?

Comment: It seems not working on ipython code, some elements are not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is, in one line is :

```
'''
@echo off & python -x "%~f0" %* & goto :eof
print "Hello 123"
'''
```

Comment: If you have no batch code to run, sure, but what's the point of embedding it in a batch script if that's the case?

Comment: But if you associate .py files with python.exe, you can just double-click those...

Comment: If you change environnement, this is not usable (not all environnment has file association). whereas bat is more universal.