# How to run python code (and not python scripts) from .bat

Tags: python, shell, batch-file, command-line

I am not sure if this is possible but I would like to run PYTHON CODE from a .bat file and not a python file.

Something like this in a .bat file:

```
python
print('Hello World')
```

Edit: I didn't add it to the question, but in addition I would like for an active python console to remain open after running the code.

Comment: You create a .py with `print('Hello World')` and then from the .bat you do `python myfile.py`

Comment: You could call a `.py` file from a `.bat` file, but `python` and `batch` are two difference languages

Comment: I know that you can call a python file from .bat. But is there a way to directly run python code?

Comment: Looks like an *XY Problem*. Why do you need this behavior?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41642050/388389

Comment: @ChristiFati. When coding python, I use IdleX because it is very lightweight. Unfortunately, it cannot handle tensorflow's outputting methodology yet (has an issue with carriage-return and backspace. So I want to run my python code that contains tensorflow in a command window shell that is still 'active' after the code is done running. Using the `exec(open(filename).read())` is perfect for what I need, but it is a bit of a bother doing it manually everytime. I would like to automate it

Comment: `.bat` indicates that the file contains commands in Windows OS command format.  What are you trying to accomplish?  The 2-line example you give is not legal in either Python or WinOS; I don't see how you expect it to work.

Comment: Ah ... so write a trivial `bat` script that takes `filename` as a command-line argument.

Comment: The problem with that is that it doesn't open a python console. I would like the code to run, and a python console to remain open

Comment: Why do you want a Python console to remain open? @CristiFati is right, this definitely feels like an XY problem.

Comment: I mentioned it above. I am using IdleX as my IDE and it's shell cannot handle tensorflow's output yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-c or -cmd` option,
`-c cmd : program passed in as string (terminates option list)`

```
python -c "print('hello world')"

hello world
```

If you try to use double quotes in your code however, that will cause a problem

```
python -c "print("hello world")"

  File "<string>", line 1
    print(hello
```

So you must escape them with a backslash

```
python -c "print(\"hello world\")"

hello world
```

Comment: So I tried it, and it closes the command prompt window really quickly. I put in this as a code and it still didn't work `>python -c "input('hello world')"`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the `>` character is not part of the script. I will remove that.

Comment: Working great, but is it possible to add multiple line codes? Also, I would like the python console to remain open afterwards

Comment: adding the `-i` option before `-c` will keep the python shell open after executing your code. As far as multi-lines in the code, I'm not sure