# How can I run a JavaScript automatically on a command-line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, command-line, windows-10

I have a simple JavaScript myScript.js with code as below;

```
var printer = function(someString){
    console.log(someString);
}

printer("This is printed on console.");
```

I'm on Windows 10 and need to be able to call `myScript.js` on a command prompt and have the code executed without doing `node myScript.js`. Is there a way to set up things so that Command prompt or PowerShell can automatically call Nodejs or other JavaScript engine?

Comment: You could install node.js for that yes. But if it's just to test some code, just open an empty browser window and play around with the console there.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818031/use-shebang-hashbang-in-windows-command-prompt

Comment: I guess associating a file extension default will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Windows can run normal shell scripts on the command line then you can add a shebang line to your Node script just like you do with shell scripts. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// your node code here
```

Also you can try to configure Node to be invoked for all files with the `.js` extension but this can be a security hazard because you may execute arbitrary code just by clocking on JavaScript files that you may have downloaded on your system so I wouldn't really recommend that.

Another alternative is to make a BAT script for you Node app:

example.bat:

```
node example.js
```

example.js:

```
// your Node script
```

That you will be able to run with just:

```
example
```

on your command line.