# windows 10 error -> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to run 'npm run build' in the terminal of parser written in React. But whenever I do this I get an error inline

```
> matrix@1.0.0 build E:\work\Parser\parser
> ./node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js --mode=development

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! matrix@1.0.0 build: `./node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js --mode=development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the matrix@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\criti\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-18T08_21_16_082Z-debug.log
```

This happens only in windows. 
When i searched for the

```
./node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js --mode=development
```

in package.json I found this to be written as

```
    "build": "./node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js --mode=development",
    "build:dev": "./node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js --mode=developement",
    "build:prod": "./node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js --mode=production",
    "build:watch": "./node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js --watch",
    "build-server": "./node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js ./parser.js -o ./parser_server.bundle.js --target='node'",
```

What is this issue ?

Comment: Sidenote: there is a typo at `"build:dev"` where you have `--mode=developement`

Comment: What version of node do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put `./node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/` on each command, simply put `webpack --mode development`.

Comment: But this Code is not what i can change as it is a git project of my Company. But when i do so i get an error ``` '--mode' is not recognized as an internal or external command,```

Comment: Ok, I guess they made it on Linux, because on Windows we use \ instead of /, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes mostly used on it by other developers. SO any idea to fix it ?

Comment: I think it's ```webpack --mode development``` actually.

Comment: On linux, this file is run via the interpreter as specified in the shebang.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818031/use-shebang-hashbang-in-windows-command-prompt#6818266
NOTE: this is a workaround... i.e. an interpreter is hardcoded to the extension...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have npx installed, try this in the command line: `npx webpack --mode=development`